# Is there something like a ServletContextListener in JSF?

Tags: jsf, listener, startup, shutdown

I would like to listen if a JSF application is started or stopped like as possible with a `ServletContextListener` in a plain Servlet web application. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

You can use an [`@ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ApplicationScoped.html) [`@ManagedBean`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) which is eagerly initialized and annotate the desired startup/shutdown hook methods with [`@PostConstruct`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) and [`@PreDestroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) respectively.

So:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class App {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // ...
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

---

Please note that this does **not** mean that you can't use a `ServletContextListener` in a JSF webapp. JSF is built on top of the Servlet API which thus means that you could just continue using it. With the new Servlet 3.0 [`@WebListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html) annotation, it's also possible to configure it without need for `web.xml`:

```
@WebListener
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: What about SystemEventListener for JSF? Or it has a different purpose?

Answer (score 2):

You could provide a system event listener for this.
See this blogpost for further details: [Bootstrapping JSF applications with system events](http://blog.oio.de/2012/05/12/bootstrapping-jsf-applications-with-systemevents/)