# When is the JSESSIONID cookie added to the response

Tags: jsf, session, cookies, jsf-2, jsessionid

I have a JSF 2.0 application, let's call it "MyApp", with a `SessionScoped` bean that uses the below code to get the session and set the path on init...

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();   //Get request from external context
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);   //Get session and don't create one if it doesn't exist
session.getServletContext().getSessionCookieConfig().setPath(""); //Set the path in the session's cookie
```

My problem is that the updated path ("") doesn't show up in the response session cookie, `JSESSIONID`, until the second request to the application. The first request gets a `JSESSIONID` cookie in the response with the default path, which includes the application's root context ("/MyApp"). If I reload the page, this second request will get a response with a `JSESSIONID` cookie that includes the updated path ("").

I can't seem to find any documentation on when the default `JSESSIONID` cookie is created and added to the response. I'm not sure if the updated session path is being set in the first response's `JSESSIONID` cookie or if it's being set and overridden by the page's default `JSESSIONID` cookie.

**Questions:**

1. When does the default JSESSIONID cookie get added to the response?
2. Is it possible to disable the page's default JSESSIONID cookie from being created?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *When does the default JSESSIONID cookie get added to the response?*

When the HTTP session is created for the first time. E.g. when JSF needs to put a newly created session scoped bean in there. So if you're writing some code in such a bean which should manipulate the session, then you're basically already too late.

Your code snippet is also a strong evidence for it. If the session was really not created, then `request.getSession(false)` would have returned `null` and subsequently, calling `session.getServletContext()` would have thrown a `NullPointerException` and you'd have asked a very different question.

---

> *Is it possible to disable the page's default JSESSIONID cookie from being created?*

I believe you're asking the wrong question. You actually want to ask how to set the session cookie path the right way.

You're supposed to configure the session cookie path in `web.xml` as below:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

If you really intend to do it programmatically for some unclear reason which is not elaborated in the question, then you should be doing this **before** the HTTP session is created for the first time. In other words, you should absolutely not be doing this in a session scoped JSF managed bean, nor be grabbing the needed `ServletContext` from the `HttpSession` itself.

Most sensible place would be a [servlet context listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177795/is-there-something-like-a-servletcontextlistener-in-jsf) or, if you really need it to be "JSF-ish", then an eagerly initialized application scoped bean. Please note that this is an **application-wide** setting, not a session-wide setting. It being a property of `ServletContext` (and not of `HttpSession`) already hints that. Thus, once you set it, it affects all newly created session cookies. [Depending on the concrete functional requirement which you told nothing about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), there may be better ways. E.g. an additional cookie.